# xslを解析するツール

Tags: xml, xsl

昔のIE6で作成したxmlとxslのページがあるのですが
Firefoxで動作させてみたら

> XSLT 変換中にエラーが発生しました: 原因不明のエラーが発生しました ()

というエラーになってしまいました
試しにIE11で動作させたところxslが読み込まれずに
xmlのデータがむき出しで表示されてしまい
IE11等はどうもxslを解析できずにIE11はとりあえずデータのみ表示
firefoxではエラーを表示しているようでした

どこで解析に失敗しているかを調べたいなのですが
xslの文法はどうも間違っていないような動作をしています(xslファイルを直接firefoxにドラッグするとちゃんとツリー構造が表示されます)

この様な場合にxmlファイルがxslファイルを読み込んだ際、どこで解析に失敗しているかを追跡できるようなツールは無いでしょうか

Comment: `xmllint` とか`XMLEDITOR.NET`とか？

Comment: xml に文法上のエラーがあるような感じがします。「xmlのデータがむき出し」で表示されている画面の上部になにか表示されていませんか？

Comment: xslt debuggerで検索すると色々出てきました。Visual Studio、Eclipse、その他色々有るようですので試してみてください。あと、問題の解決方法の回答が必要であれば、XMLとXSLファイルを載せて見てはいかがでしょう。

Comment: お二方とも。ありがとうございます。Visual Studioで出来たんですね。
xmlデータの上部には何も表示されていませんでしたが、Visual Studioでデバッグしてみたところスコープ内に変数が宣言されていないというようなエラーでした
IE6の頃とは、xslの先頭あたりで宣言した変数のスコープ範囲が変わっていたようで、変数を宣言し直したりxmlのデータ構造の変更が必要になってしまいましたが、原因はわかったので解決です